# How do I change the top padding in a navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar, yet whenever I hover the top and bottom are always enlarged. If I add `height=100px` it still doesn't change.

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
  margin: 1px auto;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

.nav:hover {
  background-color: #84a98c;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="nav">
    <h3>Home</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <h3>About</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <h3>Tools</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin:0 to h3 ?

Comment: I can not reproduce that enlarging effect. Maybe you have additional CSS applied?

Comment: The enlarging effect is the top and bottom have extra padding

Comment: You might want to look at semantics. `h3` is for headlines not for navbar items. Use `<nav>` as container and an actual unordered list of anchors. The issue will resolve tiself

Comment: Hover on `.nav` only changes the background-color nothing else, no enlargement of anything. Can't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overwriting the default CSS

Hi, the problem is caused by the default CSS for h3 elements.
By default, they have `margin-block-start: 1em;` and `margin-block-end: 1em;` atribute.

To solve your issue, simply set:

```
h3 {
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you wanted it that way but here is how I made it:

```css
                   *{
                      margin: 0;
                      padding: 0;
                    }
                    #navbar {
                      display: flex;
                      justify-content: space-between;

                      bottom: 0px;
                      top:0px;
                    }

                    h3 {
                      margin: 1px auto;
                      padding: 2px 6px; 
                      bottom: 0px;
                    }

        h3:hover {
        background-color: #84a98c;
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <body>
             <nav id="navbar">
              <h3>Home</h3>
              <h3>About</h3>
              <h3>Tools</h3>
              <h3>Contact</h3>
           </nav>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

simply adjust the padding-top

---

### Code

```
#navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
    margin: 0; /* Reset margin */
    padding: 10px 6px 2px 6px; /* Adjust top padding here */
    height: 100px; /* Fixed height */
}

.nav h3 {
    margin: 0; /* Reset margin */
}

.nav:hover {
    background-color: #84a98c;
}
```

Comment: I tried to, but definitely didn't work.